# How to merge JOptionPane and Frame into one

Tags: java, user-interface, dialog, joptionpane

Currently I have a very basic file viewer working as follows :
- in JOptionPane I browse for files, and set some variables to display (colors, line connecting etc)
- previous windows loads a frame with drawn points
[alt text http://img190.imageshack.us/img190/4443/104bu.jpg](http://img190.imageshack.us/img190/4443/104bu.jpg)
Code :
http://paste.pocoo.org/show/220066/

Now I'd like to throw it into one window, with JMenu for selecting files and changing display parameters. How to get started ? Should I rewrite everything to JDialog ?
[alt text http://img684.imageshack.us/img684/5264/lab10db.jpg](http://img684.imageshack.us/img684/5264/lab10db.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You might also like to look at [*How to Use Tool Bars*](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/toolbar.html) and [*How to Use Menus*](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html). [`ImageApp`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5129757/230513) is a typical implementation that associates menu items with the corresponding `Action` instances.

```
private class ClearAction extends AbstractAction {…}
private class ImageOpenAction extends AbstractAction {}
private Action openAction = new ImageOpenAction("Open");
private Action clearAction = new ClearAction("Clear");
…
JMenu menu = new JMenu("File");
menu.add(new JMenuItem(openAction));
menu.add(new JMenuItem(clearAction));
```

This related [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4054307/230513) adds the file chooser directly to the main frame. Here's a more elaborate [example](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/graphpanel) of connecting lines and shapes using the same principles.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the JOPtionPane as a child of the main JFrame, then add it as a child. Of course it will then cover your dots. Hence you will have to not draw your dots directly in the content pane of the main JFrame, but rather in a new JPanel that you have also added to the JFRame's content pane. Let me know if I've understood the question whatsoever.

Here's some code for how I see the setup (I'm leaving the layout problem out of this, partly because it depends on what you want to see):

```
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(new Dimension(400,400));
    frame.getContentPane().add(new JOptionPane());
    JPanel canvasForDots = new JPanel();
    frame.getContentPane().add(canvasForDots);
```