# JFileChooser High Screen Resolution incompatibility

Tags: java, jfilechooser

i'm creating a program that need display only a JFileChooser,

So i create it, and i set the LookAndFeel, like the SystemLookAndFeel, like this:

```
 UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
```

Now my problem, is that my screen have an high resolution (3840 X 2160), so when i display the JFileChooser, it appear very small, i change the size of the JFileChooser, but all the components, files and folders displayed in it, are very very small. How can i solve it???

The code of the File chooser is that:

```
    JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
    fc.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("path"));
    fc.setDialogTitle("FileChooser");
    fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);

    if(fc.showOpenDialog(frame) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){    
    }


    System.out.println(fc.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
```

This are a screen of the filechooser:[image]

[image]

Comment: Perhaps try one of the answers in this [SO Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8997160/how-to-increase-the-size-of-a-jfilechooser).

Comment: Do non-Java applications on that system have acceptably sized file choosers?