# Windows appear very small on a Retina display

Tags: java, macos, dialog, resize

I'm running Windows 10 on a Macbook Pro with Retina Display. 
And whenever I wan't to call a window from my Java-code, that could be JFileChooser for example, the window appear extreamly small. I know this might have something to do with my resolution, but is there a way to fix this?

See the photo:

[image]

Comment: Might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8997160/how-to-increase-the-size-of-a-jfilechooser

Comment: What version of Java are you using?  My understanding is that scaling support in Swing was greatly improved in recent versions of Java.