# Bringing JFileChooser on top of all windows

Tags: java, swing, openfiledialog, jfilechooser

I seem to have a problem with my very simple implementation of a file chooser dialogue that requires me to minimize Netbeans each time in order to get to it, and it gets pretty frustrating specially now with testing.

I have seen a few solutions online including [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309023/howto-bring-a-java-window-to-the-front) yet none seem to do the trick, while some other seem very lengthy and complicated for my current level.

```
private void fileSearch() {

    JFileChooser fileSelect = new JFileChooser();
    int returnVal = fileSelect.showOpenDialog(null);
    String pathToFile;

    if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        File file = fileSelect.getSelectedFile();
        pathToFile = file.getAbsolutePath();
        try {
            P.binaryFileToHexString(pathToFile);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.print("Oops! there was an error there..." + e);
        }
        System.out.println("\nYou chose to open this file: " + file.getName());
    }
}
```

Some of my try's include using;

```
.requestFocus();
.requestFocusInWindow();
.setVisible();
```

Is there a particular attribute/method I can set in order to solve the problem?

Comment: You shouldn't have to do any of this. I wonder if the reason for this is located elsewhere in your code.  For instance, do you have AWT components mixed with Swing components?

Comment: Actually no, that's the only method in the whole program that makes use of a UI the rest still is pure console. Regarding the imports am only using `java.io.File`, `java.util.Scanner` and `javax.swing.JFileChooser`

Comment: Can you create and post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) (please click on the link), a small compilable, runnable program that demonstrates your best attempt at solving this. Then we can inspect your code, run it, modify it and best be able to help you fix it.

Comment: Reformatted code; please revert if incorrect.

Comment: Would it matter if the FJFileChooser was being called from a modal JFrame?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The API for [`showOpenDialog()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#showOpenDialog%28java.awt.Component%29) refers to [`showDialog()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#showDialog%28java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.String%29), which says, "If the parent is `null`, then the dialog depends on no visible window, and it's placed in a look-and-feel-dependent position such as the center of the screen."

The example below positions the chooser in the center of the screen on my L&F. You might see how it compares to yours.

```
package gui;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPopupMenu;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;

/**
 * @see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8507521
 * @see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129294
 */
public class ImageApp extends JPanel {

    private static final int MASK =
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getMenuShortcutKeyMask();
    private JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    private Action openAction = new ImageOpenAction("Open");
    private Action clearAction = new ClearAction("Clear");
    private JPopupMenu popup = new JPopupMenu();
    private BufferedImage image;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new ImageApp().create();
            }
        });
    }

    public void create() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setTitle("Title");
        f.add(new JScrollPane(this), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu menu = new JMenu("File");
        menu.setMnemonic('F');
        menu.add(new JMenuItem(openAction));
        menu.add(new JMenuItem(clearAction));
        menuBar.add(menu);
        f.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.pack();
        f.setSize(new Dimension(640, 480));
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public ImageApp() {
        this.setComponentPopupMenu(popup);
        popup.add("Popup Menu");
        popup.add(new JMenuItem(openAction));
        popup.add(new JMenuItem(clearAction));
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (image == null) {
            return new Dimension();
        } else {
            return new Dimension(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
    }

    private class ClearAction extends AbstractAction {

        public ClearAction(String name) {
            super(name);
            this.putValue(Action.MNEMONIC_KEY, KeyEvent.VK_C);
            this.putValue(Action.ACCELERATOR_KEY,
                KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_C, MASK));
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            image = null;
            revalidate();
            repaint();
        }
    }

    private class ImageOpenAction extends AbstractAction {

        public ImageOpenAction(String name) {
            super(name);
            this.putValue(Action.MNEMONIC_KEY, KeyEvent.VK_O);
            this.putValue(Action.ACCELERATOR_KEY,
                KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_O, MASK));
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(chooser);
            if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                File f = chooser.getSelectedFile();
                try {
                    image = ImageIO.read(f);
                    revalidate();
                    repaint();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace(System.err);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your effort and help trashgod. However like I said earlier *some other (solutions) seem very lengthy and complicated for my current level*. Initially i thought it was an straight forwards error on my side, but now i realize is a bit more complicated than i thought and as it is not a *must* due it will only benefit me  during my testing procedure, i think i will leave it for now and focus on functionality. Thanks again, i will certainly try your advice when time is not a limiting factor.

Comment: No problem; I have simplified the example, accordingly. The earlier version is still accessible: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5129757/revisions

Comment: Updated example to use menu/actions/popup.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure what your problem actually is (it's probably your Netbeans.... who knows), but have you tried overriding the `createDialog` method?

Example:

```
JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser() {
   @Override
   protected JDialog createDialog(Component parent) throws HeadlessException {
       // intercept the dialog created by JFileChooser
       JDialog dialog = super.createDialog(parent);
       dialog.setModal(true);  // set modality (or setModalityType)
       return dialog;
   }
};
```

This is merely a hack solution, you should not need to do that ordinarily.

Comment: nop that did not do the trick either, am starting to think is netbeans doing the problem. Thanks though

Comment: Could instead try:

dialog.setAlwaysOnTop(true); ?

Comment: This solution worked for me when I passed my application (which is a JFrame) into the super constructor instead of passing "parent". Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
fileSelect.showOpenDialog(this)
```

Of course, `this` must be a Component of some sort (the JFrame or JPanel of your main interface).
All dialogs need to have a parent component if you wish them to come to the front.