# How to do system short cuts cross platform integration in Java?

Tags: java, cross-platform, keyboard-shortcuts

As you may know, the short-cuts of save in Mac OS X is 
`Cmd+S` on Windows is `Ctrl+S`, and the short cuts of close an application is 
`Cmd+Q` and Windows is `Alt + F4`. But the question is how to do these in a java application? Do I need to find all the short cuts I used in the application, and match the related function depends on different OSs. Any recommendations? Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `Toolkit` method [`getMenuShortcutKeyMask()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#getMenuShortcutKeyMask%28%29) is useful in this context. While the method returns `Event.CTRL_MASK` on Windows, it returns `Event.META_MASK` on Mac OS X. The resulting mask can be used to construct the `KeyStroke` used in a menu item's [`setAccelerator()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JMenuItem.html#setAccelerator%28javax.swing.KeyStroke%29) method.

Comment: A complete example is examined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5129757/230513).