# accelerator key value java.awt.event.KeyEvent

Tags: java, swing, junit, key-events

I'm using accelerator to perform <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> then <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> using java/junit
is there a way to get the value of <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to check it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8105344/230513), a menu accelerator key stroke such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> should be constructed in a platform independent manner:

```
int mask = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getMenuShortcutKeyMask();
JMenuItem menuItem = new JMenuItem(…);
menuItem.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_V, mask));
```

For comparison, you can get the menu item's `KeyStroke` via [`getAccelerator()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JMenuItem.html#getAccelerator%28%29) or from any `KeyEvent` via [`KeyStroke.getKeyStrokeForEvent()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/KeyStroke.html#getKeyStrokeForEvent%28java.awt.event.KeyEvent%29).

Answer (score 1):

If you mean how do I simulate the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> events within a JUnit test for a Swing application, then I would recommend looking at [FEST](http://code.google.com/p/fest/). Using FEST, you can simulate mouse clicks, or key presses. To simulate a 
<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, you would do:

```
// import static java.awt.event.KeyEvent.*;          
dialog.list("employees").pressKey(VK_CONTROL)
                        .pressAndReleaseKey(VK_V)
                        .releaseKey(VK_CONTROL);
```

and so on. For more information on simulating user input, see the wiki [Simulating Keyboard Input](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/FEST/Simulating+Keyboard+Input).