# Mac Keyboard Shortcuts with Nimbus LAF

Tags: java, macos, swing, keyboard-shortcuts, nimbus

Is there a way to use Nimbus LAF (Look And Feel) on OS X while still being able to use the <kbd>Meta</kbd> key for cut/copy/paste and select-all operations?

I currently have the following code in my Swing app's main method, which changes up the LAF based on the operating system (default for OS X, Nimbus for all others):

```
if (!System.getProperty("os.name", "").startsWith("Mac OS X")) {
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(LicenseInspectorUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(LicenseInspectorUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(LicenseInspectorUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(LicenseInspectorUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

I do this as a workaround because Nimbus overrides the keyboard shortcuts for cut/copy/paste and select-all on OS X (<kbd>Meta</kbd> key versus <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key).  I would prefer to use Nimbus all the time, if only the keyboard shortcuts weren't overridden.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the [`getMenuShortcutKeyMask()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#getMenuShortcutKeyMask%28%29) method works with `NimbusLookAndFeel` to enable the <kbd>⌘</kbd> key, as shown in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5129757/230513). See also this related [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8105344/230513).

In the particular case of a `JTextField`, you can use the mask in a [key binding](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) that evokes the original action.

```
int MASK = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getMenuShortcutKeyMask();
JTextField jtf = new JTextField("Test");
jtf.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A, MASK), "select-all");
jtf.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_C, MASK), "copy");
jtf.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_X, MASK), "cut");
jtf.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_V, MASK), "paste");
```

Comment: I don’t see how this answers the question. Even if you call getMenuShortcutKeyMask() when registering custom keyboard shortcuts, this does not fix the incorrect Ctrl-C, Ctrl-V, etc. in a default Swing TextField when using NimbusLookAndFeel on OSX.

Comment: @yonran: I've elaborated above.

Comment: Seems that the action names differ per component. So to map the "copy" action, you will also need to map DefaultEditorKit.copyAction.

Comment: @JouniAro: Not necessarily; the actions are already in the text field's `ActionMap`, placed there (by name) during the UI delegate's initialization; see this [article](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/10/key-bindings/).

Comment: Sorry, I mean per component type. So for every Table, the ActionMap contains "copy", whereas for every TextField it contains "copy-to-clipboard" (=DefaultEditorKit.copyAction)

Answer (score 1):

Different components use different keys, so to map all of them, you will have to define different keys. For example (base found from [here](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel)):

```
private void addOSXKeyStrokes(InputMap inputMap) {
  inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_C, KeyEvent.META_DOWN_MASK), DefaultEditorKit.copyAction);
  inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_X, KeyEvent.META_DOWN_MASK), DefaultEditorKit.cutAction);
  inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_V, KeyEvent.META_DOWN_MASK), DefaultEditorKit.pasteAction);
  inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A, KeyEvent.META_DOWN_MASK), DefaultEditorKit.selectAllAction);
  inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_C, KeyEvent.META_DOWN_MASK), "copy");
  inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A, KeyEvent.META_DOWN_MASK), "selectAll");
}
```

This can then be mapped to different components as follows:

```
// This must be performed immediately after the LaF has been set
if (System.getProperty("os.name", "").startsWith("Mac OS X")) {
  // Ensure OSX key bindings are used for copy, paste etc
  // Use the Nimbus keys and ensure this occurs before any component creation
  addOSXKeyStrokes((InputMap) UIManager.get("EditorPane.focusInputMap"));
  addOSXKeyStrokes((InputMap) UIManager.get("FormattedTextField.focusInputMap"));
  addOSXKeyStrokes((InputMap) UIManager.get("PasswordField.focusInputMap"));
  addOSXKeyStrokes((InputMap) UIManager.get("TextField.focusInputMap"));
  addOSXKeyStrokes((InputMap) UIManager.get("TextPane.focusInputMap"));
  addOSXKeyStrokes((InputMap) UIManager.get("TextArea.focusInputMap"));
  addOSXKeyStrokes((InputMap) UIManager.get("Table.ancestorInputMap"));
  addOSXKeyStrokes((InputMap) UIManager.get("Tree.focusInputMap"));
}
```

A full list of Aqua (OS X Look and Feel) action names is [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/macosx/classes/com/apple/laf/AquaKeyBindings.java)

Comment: Kudos for source link!

Comment: Thanks. Took me quite a while to find a clear example, so I wanted to share it here as well - with my own additions.

Comment: This is great! Thanks. Now can anyone tell me how to import the com.apple.laf.AquaKeyBindings class? I can't find a maven dependency for it, or a library. (I don't usually need to import these classes, but I know I've done it in the distant past.)

Comment: In the first method, why do you have two mappings for copy and selectAll? You map the same keystroke to DefaultEditorKit.copyAction and to "copy". That doesn't make sense. Am I missing something?