# How to map standard Copy action to a popup menu in Swing

Tags: java, swing

I have a simple wish for my Swing UI: there is a standard Copy action that is mapped to the `InputMap` of a component. Next there is a popup menu in this same component and I would like to add a menu item that runs the copy action and of course would show the keyboard shortcut that is in the inputMap.

This is the mac-version of the mapping, which I finally managed to add as a generic rule with the help of [this](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel), by realising that some components use "copy", whereas others use DefaultEditorKit.copyAction:

```
inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_C, KeyEvent.META_DOWN_MASK), DefaultEditorKit.copyAction);
inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_C, KeyEvent.META_DOWN_MASK), "copy");
```

Now, I can find the action for a table, for example with

```
ActionMap actionMap = myTable.getActionMap();
Action action = actionMap.get("copy");
```

Now, I use the Action to create the MenuItem:

```
JPopupMenu popupMenu = new JPopupMenu();
JMenuItem item = new JMenuItem(action);
popupMenu.add(item);
table.setComponentPopupMenu(popupMenu);
```

As a result, I see the menu item, but it does not copy anything, although the shortcut key that is mapped to the same action, does copy. I can even define the shortcut (which I seemingly have to define myself, but also just as a hint for the user that these things are somehow linked together):

```
int MASK = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getMenuShortcutKeyMask();
KeyStroke keyStroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_C, MASK);
item.setAccelerator(keyStroke);
```

So, what am I missing? I even tried to define the action listener specifically, to no avail:

```
item.addActionListener(myTable.getActionForKeyStroke(keyStroke));
```

Sounds funny that the keyboard shortcut works automatically (I just had to figure out how to make the Cmd-key work in Mac instead of Ctrl (which took only a couple of hours)) and now I cannot make the menu entry linked to the existing action by no means (even after working for another couple of hours).

Comment: See [*What is the JTable CTRL+C event's name?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14356859/230513) for some alternatives.

Comment: Hmm, seems that myTable.getInputMap().get(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_C, MASK)) gives 'null'. But "copy" is the name that is in the actionMap, and actionMap.get("copy") gives a valid Action.

Comment: You forgot `WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT`.

Comment: Aha - no I didn't forget - I did not know about it :) I admit, this is the first time I am doing anything related, so I am struggling, but I also didn't expect anything this complicated, either... Well, now I get "copy" from the InputMap, as expected. - The question remains: how can I trigger that action from code or from a menu entry so that it works with mouse action also?

Comment: You might try @camickr's approach, cited above.

Comment: Aha - again ;) I didn't notice that your question was a link. Seems I am a bit ignorant today. Anyways, @camrick's ActionMapAction really did the trick. I must admit that I would have never been able to solve this myself. Simple stuff... Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To recap from the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45811987/how-to-map-standard-copy-action-to-a-popup-menu-in-swing?noredirect=1#comment78586280_45811987), here's a full implementation—modified from the [original](http://www.camick.com/java/source/ActionMapAction.java) in the article cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15286504/230513)—with the `addCopyAndSelectAll` method that adds a standard "copy" and "selectAll" menu items. Note that this works mainly with the `JTable` controls, since they use these action names. Other component types may be initialized to other action names as I've mentioned in my answer to [the other issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9780028/mac-keyboard-shortcuts-with-nimbus-laf/9781578).

```
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPopupMenu;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;

/*
 * The ActionMapAction class is a convenience class that allows you to use an installed Action as an
 * Action or ActionListener on a separate component.
 *
 * It can be used on components like JButton or JMenuItem that support an Action as a property of
 * the component. Or it can be added to the same above components as an ActionListener.
 *
 * The benefit of this class is that a new ActionEvent will be created such that the source of the
 * event is the component the Action belongs to, not the component that was "clicked". Otherwise in
 * many cases a ClassCastException will be thrown when the Action is invoked.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ActionMapAction extends AbstractAction {
  /**
   * @param parent
   * @param popupMenu
   */
  public static void addCopyAndSelectAll(JComponent parent, JPopupMenu popupMenu) {
    // Must use ActionMapAction to link between the MenuItem and Table
    // The "copy" action, for example must be called from a Table, not from MenuItem
    Action copyAction = new ActionMapAction("Copy", parent, "copy");

    JMenuItem copyItem = new JMenuItem(copyAction);
    int MASK = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getMenuShortcutKeyMask();
    copyItem.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_C, MASK));
    popupMenu.add(copyItem);

    Action selAction = new ActionMapAction(UiMessages.INSTANCE.get("Select All", parent, "selectAll");

    JMenuItem selItem = new JMenuItem(selAction);
    selItem.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A, MASK));
    popupMenu.add(selItem);

    parent.setComponentPopupMenu(popupMenu);
  }

  private Action originalAction;
  private JComponent component;

  private String actionCommand = "";

  /**
   * Replace the default Action for the given KeyStroke with a custom Action
   *
   * @param name the name parameter of the Action
   * @param componet the component the Action belongs to
   * @param actionKey the key to identify the Action in the ActionMap
   */
  public ActionMapAction(String name, JComponent component, String actionKey) {
    super(name);

    originalAction = component.getActionMap().get(actionKey);

    if (originalAction == null) {
      String message = "no Action for action key: " + actionKey;
      throw new IllegalArgumentException(message);
    }

    this.component = component;
  }

  /**
   * Invoke the original Action using the original component as the source of the event.
   */
  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    e = new ActionEvent(component, ActionEvent.ACTION_PERFORMED, actionCommand, e.getWhen(), e.getModifiers());

    originalAction.actionPerformed(e);
  }

  public void setActionCommand(String actionCommand) {
    this.actionCommand = actionCommand;
  }
}
```