# Control key usage in Java/Swing on Mac

Tags: java, macos, swing, ctrl

I got a Swing Application that relies on mouse events combined with two modifier keys (Ctrl & Shift) to control the UI. It works flawlessly on Windows and Linux.

Now, I'd like to make this app running on the Macintosh platform as well. The UI doesn't work out-of-box because the Control key seems to interfere with the right click on my MacBook Pro.

Is there any possibility to get Ctrl-click events working on Mac or should I consider using another key (Alt/Option) instead?

I only care of Mac OS X 10.9 and higher and Java 8.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As shown [here](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25085?locale=en_US), Mac OS X uses <kbd>control</kbd>-click to simulate a right-click when using a single-button input device. Using <kbd>option</kbd>-click is a common alternative; [jfreechart](/questions/tagged/jfreechart) is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19284972/230513). For convenience, you may be able to leverage `getMenuShortcutKeyMask()`, discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8105344/230513), which returns `Event.CTRL_MASK` on Windows/Linux and `Event.META_MASK` on Mac OS X.