# How to get focus in JPopupMenu

Tags: java, swing, focus, jpopupmenu

I am an experienced Java programmer, but a Swing newbie so please bear with me.

I wish to have a JPopupWindow which has keyboard focus.  I want to respond to arrow keys, escape (to close the menu) and Enter (to invoke the item).  Must I add a KeyListener to the menu and code all this myself, or is there some sort of "mode" I can set to activate this behavior which seems like it ought to be standard.

The standard Swing tutorial section on JPopupMenus speaks only of mnemonics and accelerators.  I don't particularly want those.

Hard to believe that this is totally against the grain of JPopupMenu.

What is best way to get something like I want implemented?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once you do `jpopupMenu.show(Component invoker, int x, int y)`it will automatically respond to keyboard as you want. If this is not working then you might need to fix some other issue i.e some other component is snatching away focus from the menu when it should not etc.

Comment: hmm.  I was using setVisible(true) rather than show() but I see that show() is deprecated in favor of setVisible()/

Comment: I was talking about show(Component invoker, int x, int y) method that I have used in my code. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: That is the answer.  I wasn't properly tied to a component.  Trashgod's reply was also necessary to do that.  Thanks to both of you.

Comment: Well, I spoke a little too soon.  This isn't completely solved, but still 90% pf the way there.  Arrow Keys function as desired.  Enter key does not make the selection (but space key does) and ESC key does not cancel the menu.

Comment: I actually tested and it works fine for me including ESC/ENTER keys. I am just creating JPopupMenu adding few JMenuItems to it and then calling show(myButton, 0, 0) on it. I am creating the popupmenu on clicking the button.

Comment: Hmm, possibly those keys are being eaten somewhere else.

Comment: Possibly some component is registering key-bindings for these keys even when it is not focussed. Probably http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html may help.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `KeyListener`, I'd recommend adding [*Action*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) instances to your [`JPopupMenu`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JPopupMenu.html). Use [`setComponentPopupMenu()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setComponentPopupMenu%28javax.swing.JPopupMenu%29) to add the popup to your panel.

Comment: thanks, your input, together with AKJ's above, got this working.

Comment: Excellent; for reference, there's a recently updated example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5129757/230513).