# How to add an Image to Form in java

Tags: java, image, swing, jdeveloper

I am designing a form in java using JDeveloper.
I am new to JDeveloper.
In JDeveloper tool I didn't found any option to directly add image to form like .Net.
And I don't know how to add image to form manually.
is there any other way to solve it out.
So please help me to solve it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As simple as this :

```java
image = ImageIO.read(new File(path));
JLabel picLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
```

Yayy! Now your image is a swing component ! add it to a frame or panel or anything like you usually do! Probably need a repainting too , like

```java
jpanel.add(picLabel);
jpanel.repaint();
```

Comment: +1 This is easy and flexible; see also [`ImageApp`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5129757/230513) for a different approach.

Answer (score 2):

Don't know about JDeveloper but in code you have following possibilities:

1. Create an `ImageIcon` of the image then set that to a jLabel and add jLabel to your frame.
2. <del>Override `paintComponents()` of your frame to draw image using Graphics in it.</del> {Not sure about this}
3. Override `paintComponent()` of some panel or any other component to draw image using Graphics in it and then add that component to frame..

Comment: *"2. Override paintComponent() of your frame"*  `JFrame` has no `paintComponent()` method.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: I think its paintComponents() for JFrame. But still not sure.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Labels as Sanjay says.

also using layered pane you can use as background image.

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing it this way:

1. `ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("imageName.png"));`
2. `JLabel lblImage = new JLabel(image);`

line 1 of the code will get the image ensure that the image is in the same folder you are saving your work