# Rendering Image into label

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I have a label. I want to render image into it. But the following code would do anything.

```
 CardLayout cl = (CardLayout) (mainPanel.getLayout());
        cl.show(mainPanel, "newPersonaCard");
        BufferedImage myPicture = ImageIO.read(new    File("C:\\Desktop\\Documents\\Pictures\\always.jpg"));
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(myPicture);
        icon.getImage().flush();
```

I am using netbean designer.

Comment: try packing the container again.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  But load the image on button-click, perhaps hot-linked from one of [these images](http://pscode.org/media/#image).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8530698/977676 This solutions works, and if you still have problem, post an SSCCE !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, in some cases there issue with repainting `Icon` in the `JLabel`, then you have to call,

```
myIcon.getImage().flush();
myLabel.setIcon(myIcon);
```

rest of methods is implemented in the `Icon` and `JLabel` correctly

Comment: @ Kitex no idea, really you have to edit your question with SSCCE and use images from (for example) from (@Andrew Thompson) because nobody can see rest of your code and (don't want if I have got my) access to your image saved on your HDD :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
.
.
File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();

JLabel label = new JLabel();
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(file.getAbsolutePath());
label.setIcon(icon);
//add label to panel
```

Comment: What is with the `setLocation` and `setSize` calls ? A label is perfectly capable of calculating its own size, and the layout manager will determine the location

Answer (score 1):

```
fileChooser.showDialog(saveBtn2, null);
File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
System.out.println("The path to file "+file.getAbsolutePath());          
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(file.getAbsolutePath());
pictureLbl.setIcon(icon);
```

Comment: I doubt, though that `revalidate()` is required for `setIcon(...)` now. No need to revalidate.