# image resize to fit on JPanel

Tags: java, image, swing, jpanel

I have JPanel Which will load images.

Since images will not have the same width and height as the JPanel, I want to make the image resize and fit in the JPanel.

Comment: for better help sooner edit your question with a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) demonstrated your issue with Image and JPanel

Comment: can you post the relevant code regarding the image and JPanel?

Comment: I have a class which extends JPanel and using paintComponent i m inserting image on it.. n i m passing image path in constructor.

Comment: *"I have JPanel Which will load images."*  If these are user images, it might be best to put them in a `JLabel` inside a `JScrollPane`.  You don't want that 'portrait' style image of your mother stretched all across the view port.  ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Read on this article, [The Perils of Image.getScaledInstance()](https://community.oracle.com/docs/DOC-983611)

Now **IF you STILL prefer** you can use something like,

```
Image scaledImage = originalImage.getScaledInstance(jPanel.getWidth(),jPanel.getHeight(),Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
```

this before loading the image to your JPanel, probably like discussed [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8530698/977676).

Comment: But the problem here is i m not getting jpanels width and height..     I have class which extends JPanel and i m putting image on this panel. when i try to get width and height it shows 0.0

Comment: @Azuu : Then override it's `getPreferredSize()` as you doing with `paintComponent(...)` method and let is return some value e.g. `return new Dimension(500, 500);` , that will do, now you can calculate it's height and width.

Answer (score 6):

I know this is quite old, but maybe this helps other people

use this class instead of a normal JLabel and pass an ImageIcon when using setIcon(#);

```
private class ImageLabel extends JLabel{
    private Image _myimage;

    public ImageLabel(String text){
        super(text);
    }

    public void setIcon(Icon icon) {
        super.setIcon(icon);
        if (icon instanceof ImageIcon)
        {
            _myimage = ((ImageIcon) icon).getImage();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        g.drawImage(_myimage, 0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight(), null);
    }
}
```

Comment: This, for me at least, was more practical than the above. I actually had the same class written, but I didn't have the width and height arguments. Thank you.

Comment: This does work, but obviously breaks image scale. So for images where width and height are not equal this will introduce warping.