# Synth - setting background to JFrame

Tags: java, swing, background, jframe, synth

I'm creating an app in Java using Swing and Synth. I want to set **image** background to JFrame using Synth. How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There weren't better solution, so I decided to draw the background directly on the JFrame using Java2D (although I don't have the code now).

Answer (score 1):

JFrame haven't implemented Color, you can do that

1) [JFrame#getContentpane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setContentPane%28java.awt.Container%29).[setBackground(Color c)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setBackground%28java.awt.Color%29)

better would be

2) [JFrame#add](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#add%28java.awt.Component%29)([JPanel#setBackground(Color c)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setBackground%28java.awt.Color%29))

Comment: No no no... I want to set background using Synth, not pure Swing. Btw., I forgot to add that I want image background. But thanks for help.

Comment: Although it's not L&F specific, maybe something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5129757/230513)?