# How to prevent JMenuItem from closing Menu upon clicking the JMenuItem

Tags: java, swing, jmenu, jmenuitem

How do I prevent a `JMenuItem` from closing the menu when the `JMenuItem` is clicked?

The `JMenuItem` is enabled.

So this is the scenario, I have 3 `JMenuItems`:

`JMenuItem: A, B, C`;

C displays an integer `X`.

A and B are used to increment or decrement `X` by a value of 1.
If A or B is clicked, the default nature is that the menu will close upon click.
I want to be able to repeatedly click A or B and have the menu remain up, and perform the associated 'action' upon each click.

Thanks!

Comment: please edit your post with code in http://sscce.org/ form

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, using a menu to do this may be the wrong approach.  `JSpinner` seems more appropriate.  However, to do this with a `JMenuItem` you can subclass the `MenuItemUI` of the `LookAndFeel` you are using, and override the `doClick(...)` method so that `clearSelectionPath()` is not called, which closes the menu when the item is clicked.

Example, if you are using the Motif `LookAndFeel` you can do this:

```
menuItem.setUI(new MotifMenuItemUI() {
    @Override
    protected void doClick(MenuSelectionManager msm) {
        menuItem.doClick(0);
    }
});
```

I haven't ever tried this myself but I think it will work.

Comment: As an alternative to changing the UI delegate, consider [`Action`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html), shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5129757/230513).

Comment: Well this stopped the menu from displaying the hover animation on that item, but clicking it still closes the menu. Could you please check it?

Comment: @TomášZato for `JCheckBoxMenuItem`s, I found that I could just substitute them with `JCheckBox`es and they would function just as well. For `JMenuItems` perhaps a `JButton` would work.
([Source](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/23952024/How-do-I-tell-a-JMenuItem-to-not-close-the-JMenu.html))