# Preventing JMenuItem from closing JMenu upon a click

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel, jmenu, jmenuitem

How can I do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9198935/3251857) while I'm using multiple LAFs:

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
```

Comment: don't - you'll confuse your users!

Comment: @kleopatra, but if I want to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my problem this way:

```
public class MyMenuItem extends JMenuItem {

    public MyMenuItem(String text) {
        super(text);
    }

    @Override
    protected void processMouseEvent(MouseEvent evt) {
        if (evt.getID() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED  && contains(evt.getPoint())) {
            doClick();
            setArmed(true);
        } else
            super.processMouseEvent(evt);
    }

}
```