# How to click on JMenuBar items without closing the item listing?

Tags: java, swing, jmenu, jmenuitem, jmenubar

I'm using JMenuBar, I would like that when clicking on the menu items, the menu will keep showing the items, without closing after the click, or if not possible, could make a command to open the items again.

Comment: Check out [Keeping Menus Open](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/09/12/keeping-menus-open/) for a possible solution.

Comment: Check with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9198530/how-to-prevent-jmenuitem-from-closing-menu-upon-clicking-the-jmenuitem