# How to auto adjust window size in Swing

Tags: java, image, swing, jframe

I need to display an image in a JFrame. How can I make the window size to be automatically adjusted based on the size of the image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1.in the case that you put image as `Icon / ImageIcon` to the `JLabel` then

- have to test for `MaximumSize` for `JFrame` that returned [Toolkit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html) for concrete monitor
- if `PreferedSize` is lower than `MaximumSize` size then call `JFrame#pack()`
- otherwise have to call `setSize()`

2.in the case that you put image as `Icon / ImageIcon` by using `Custom Painting` to the `JComponent`, `JPanel`, `JLabel` e.i. then

- then this `JComponen`t must to returns `PreferredSize`

  a) call `JFrame#pack()` if `PreferedSize` is lower than `MaximumSize`,

  b) otherwise have to call `JFrame#setSize()`

  c) by assume that you don't use `Image#getScalledInstance`

3.I'd be to use `Icon` in the `JLabel`, there is only one issue that image can be smaller then expected size on the screen, but no issue with that, is pretty possible to centering image to the `JLabel.CENTER` to the `JLabel`

Comment: Also consider `JScrollPane`, shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5129757/230513).

Comment: Example to **Point 2** using ***Custom Painting*** is shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11372350/1057230)

Comment: don't quite understand the overall logic: a) typically, max is waaay big (so it's safe enough to simply ignore in first approximation) and waayy greater than pref b) a JLabel returns a reasonable size for pref, pack is all that's needed c) _otherwise_ would be pref > max which would be an illegalState that has to be fixed (instead of forcing the actual size to larger (not sure if the frame would oblige) 1. and 2. look very mush the same (except for manual painting and custom override of getPref)