# Creating a customized JFrame

Tags: java, swing, opacity, bufferedimage, shapes

[image]

I know how to create a translucent window but I included that just for the sake of completeness.
Now here is what I am trying to do....

### Create an undecorated JFrame with 60% opacity

### Soft window edge.

Referring to the image above, you can see that the edges are sharp and well-defined. I want to make them soft

### Give it a rounded-rectangle shape.

I can give a shape using `AWTUtilities.setWindowShape(Window,Shape)` but I was wondering how I can create a **rounded rectangle**.

### Create a reflection of the `BufferedImage` to be used as background

*Why don't you use Photoshop?* you may ask but it is tedious to create a reflection of every image that u wanna try to use as a background. Instead I was wondering if there is a programmatic way to:

Take a `BufferedImage`

Flip it vertically. In other words, upside down.

change its opacity to a desired value

set size of `JFrame` to be twice of the original buffered image

## Help!!!

---

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.*;
public class ImageReflection extends JFrame{
    public ImageReflection(){
        ImageIcon baseIcon = new ImageIcon("src/images/mentalist-logo.png");
        ImageIcon reflectIcon = new ImageIcon("src/images/mentalist-logo.png");
        JLabel baseLabel = new JLabel(baseIcon);
        JLabel reflectLabel = new JLabel();

        Graphics2D g2D = (Graphics2D) reflectIcon.getImage().getGraphics();
        g2D.rotate(180);
        reflectLabel.setIcon(reflectIcon);


        this.add(reflectLabel);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.pack();

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ImageReflection();
    }
}
```

I get an `UnsupportedOperationException` at `Graphics2D g2D = (Graphics2D) reflectIcon.getImage().getGraphics();`.
This is my code to turn the image upside down.

Comment: I have solved always with JWindow, it was easier than with JFrame.

Comment: where is your code you tried? writing in big fonts won't help you much I guess

Comment: @vishal_aim I said, I can only change the opacity.

Comment: you can try with `JWindow` and `( (JComponent) initWindow.getContentPane ( ) ).setBorder(new CompoundBorder(..))` and `AWTUtilities.setWindowOpaque ( initWindow, false );` I created my custom rounded border and used here

Comment: @vishal_aim if you have a possible solution, please post it as an answer. It makes it easier for folks to find later.

Comment: The question is how to create the GUI as I stated. I could fix a few of them . WHat is left is creating a reflection

Comment: there is transparency (4th. paramaters for Color) and translucency, have to accepting those two f*** differiences

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is left is creating a reflection.

You can alter the graphics context's `AffineTransform` like this:

```
BufferedImage newImage = new BufferedImage(
    oldImage.getWidth(), oldImage.getHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
Graphics2D g2d = newImage.createGraphics();
g2d.translate(0, newImage.getHeight());
g2d.scale(1, -1);
g2d.drawImage(oldImage, 0, 0, null);
g2d.dispose();
```

Comment: Adding my code to the question, check it out. I get an exception.

Comment: Right; `getGraphics()` is only valid for images created with `createImage(w, h)`; use `ImageIO.read()` to get `oldImage ` as a `BufferedImage`, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5129757/230513).

Answer (score 2):

possibly you can try something like this (may be of some help if not all), this is what I tried earlier:

```
final JWindow initWindow = new JWindow();
SwingWorker<Object, Object> task = new SwingWorker<Object, Object>()
            {
        public Object doInBackground() 
        {
            //show init window
            //....
            initWindow.getContentPane().add(text);

           ( (JComponent) initWindow.getContentPane ( ) ).setBorder(new CompoundBorder(new CustomRoundedBorder(), new LineBorder(new Color(...)));

           AWTUtilities.setWindowOpaque ( initWindow, false );

           initWindow.setAlwaysOnTop(true);

           initWindow.setVisible(true);
             //....
            return null;
        }
        public void done() 
        {
        }
    };
    task.execute();
```