# Text duplication

Tags: java, swing

I am working on simple text editor and on main panel, I have JList with currently opened files (CDocument class) and active document, which contents is shown (also CDocument class). I store opened files (CDocument objects) in vector and on the right side the active document is shown.[image]

Now, at program start, there is no active document and opened document list is empty. After I click File->New, I create new, empty object from class CDocument. If I enter something into active document area (the red region on screenshot) and then I reclick File->New, I get new, empty (with no text - I've doublechecked with ) CDocument object. But, the text from previous active document still shows into newly created (red region - newly empty CDocument). I am busting my brain here because I do not know why?! Here is File->New code chunck:
`

```
if(e.getSource()==this.menuItemFileNew())
{
    CDocument currentDocument=new CDocument();

    if(this.panelMain().documentActive()!=null)
    {
        this.panelMain().remove(this.panelMain().documentActive());
    }

    this.panelMain().openedDocuments().add(currentDocument);
    this.panelMain().setDocumentActive(currentDocument);

    this.panelMain().add(panelMain().documentActive().pane(),
            BorderLayout.CENTER);
    this.panelMain().documentActive().addKeyListener(this);
    this.panelMain().documentActive().requestFocus();

    this.menuItemFileSave().setEnabled(true);
    this.menuItemFileSaveAs().setEnabled(true);
    this.menuItemFileClose().setEnabled(true);
    this.menuItemFileCloseAll().setEnabled(true);

    this.toolBarFileSwitcher().panelActiveDocumentInfo().
            panelFileSizeInfo().updatePanel(this.panelMain().documentActive().getText().length(),
                false);

    this.toolBarFileSwitcher().listOpenedFiles().model().addElement(currentDocument.filename());
    this.toolBarFileSwitcher().listOpenedFiles().setSelectedIndex(this.toolBarFileSwitcher().listOpenedFiles().model().size()-1);
    this.toolBarFileSwitcher().setVisible(true);
}
```

`

Why is text shown, I've tried updateUI, repaint, nothing works!

Comment: A prediction: that we'll not be able to tease out what's going on with your program based on this snippet above, that instead we'll need a small compilable and runnable version of your problem, an [sscce](http://sscce.org). I hope that I'm wrong, but I don't think so.

Comment: can I send here a jar file, so you can run it?

Comment: We're volunteers and most of us are too busy for this sort of thing, myself included. Besides that would go against the philosophy of this site.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Action`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) to encapsulate functionality related to your `CDocument` data type. This will help ensure that *all* invocations are consistent. This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5129757/230513) manages images, while this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4039359/230513) illustrates a menu of files.