# Adding a global keyboard shorcut to dynamically added buttons

Tags: java, swing

I have some difficulties with setting a shortcut to my dynamically added buttons. Buttons are on dynamically added panel. I want to add keyboard shortcuts to these buttons, like so:

```
ctrl+1 -> button1
ctrl+2 -> button2
etc.
```

Buttons are added by an algorithm, so I don't know how many of them there will be(min 0, max 5). I would like to call these buttons with Global (working in whole panel) keyboard shortcuts. I am wondering how  to achieve this, when the text on my button is made dynamically like this:

```
getNewAmountQueryButton(label)
```

which makes this:

```
private JButton getNewAmountQueryButton(final Decimal label) {
    JButton temp = new JButton(label.toString());
    ...
```

I tried adding keylistener but it works only when I have a focus on a button:

```
button.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(final KeyEvent e) {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if ((e.getKeyCode() == getKeyCode()) && ((e.getModifiers() & InputEvent.CTRL_MASK) != 0)) {
                        model.setAmount(model.getAmount().add(label));
                        field().selectAll();
                        refreshDisplay();
                    }
                }
            });
    });
```

Do you know how can I do this? I wanted to add listener to top-level panel, but as I use `model.setAmount(model.getAmount().add(label));`to refresh some textField it is impossible due to lack of this `label` parameter.

Any idea? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

Comment: Will KeyBind action be global? Or it will work just with focus on the button?

Comment: If you had read the link provided by @MadProgrammer you would have seen that key bindings allow you to choose between the different behaviors (ancestor of focused, in focused window, when focused)

Comment: @Borewitsch More global then `KeyListener` will ever be

Comment: @MadProgrammer Could you write your comment as an aswer so I could accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is recommend that you use [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html).

Bascially, they don't suffer from the same focus issues as `KeyListeners`

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Action`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) to encapsulate each button's behvior. You can specify the desired `MNEMONIC_KEY`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5129757/230513), and you can add a binding to the `ACCELERATOR_KEY`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5797965/230513).