# Text Document Editor in Java Swing Application

Tags: java, swing, editor, document

I am in the process of developing a Java application using Swing. I want to open a document file inside the application where a user can select some content. On right click, it should give list of all the fields above, when user clicks on a field the selected part from the document goes to that particular field.

Please refer the image:

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question to indicate where you're having trouble: layout? selection? popup? copy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can select text in a [`JTextComponent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html) and bring up a [`JPopupMenu`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html#popup). The menu should have an [`Action`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) for each field that copies the selected text to the corresponding field. This related [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5129757/230513) illustrates some of the concepts.

Comment: I have found the solution for loading the file that I had while writing this question. Just tell me how to select and add elements to the fields.

Comment: Use `getSelectedText()` to fetch the text from your `JTextComponent`, and use `setText()` to store it in the corresponding `JTextField`.