# right click popup menu is not working properly (in jtable)

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jmenuitem, jpopupmenu

its working for first time but after deleting some line it shows blank on popup menu in right click. i think its because of refresh method but i couldn't solve it.

```
private void refresh() {
    List<String> head = new ArrayList<>();
    head.add("ID");
    head.add("П/Н");

    EnlargeAlisTableModel model = new EnlargeAlisTableModel(dbsql.listAlis(), head) {
    // *****************
    };
    tblEnlarge.setModel(model);

    tblEnlarge.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            if (e.isPopupTrigger()) {
                popup.removeAll();
                JMenuItem delete = new JMenuItem("Delete");
                delete.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        if (tblEnlarge.getSelectedRow() == -1) {
                        } else {
                            DeleteEnlargeAlis da = new DeleteEnlargeAlis(null, true, Integer.parseInt(tblEnlarge.getValueAt(tblEnlarge.getSelectedRow(), 0).toString()));
                            da.setVisible(true);
                            if (da.isOk()) {
                                Ok = true;
                                refresh();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
                //  ********************
                popup.add(delete);
                popup.show(e.getComponent(), e.getX(), e.getY());
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Use `setComponentPopupMenu()`, shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5129757/230513).

Comment: Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/), such as the one [cited](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5129757/230513), that exhibits any problems you encounter.