# How to access jtextPane in a different form?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtextpane

I am developing an application where, when I select a value(file) from list it should be opened in jTextPane of a different form. I am using two panels one is mainpanel where my list is shown and one is ExcelSheet, when i click on a list value then mainpanel is closed and new form ExcelSheet is displayed but not the content of doc file in jTextPane.

```
XWPFWordExtractor extractor=null;
    File file=null;
    String str=(String) list.getSelectedValue();
    mainPanel.setVisible(false);
    new ExcelSheet().setVisible(true);
    ExcelSheet obj=new ExcelSheet();
        try {
             file=new File("C:\\Users\\Siddique Ansari\\Documents\\CV Parser\\"+str);   


        FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath());
        XWPFDocument document=new XWPFDocument(fis);
        extractor = new XWPFWordExtractor(document);
        String fileData = extractor.getText();
        Document doc = obj.jTextPane1.getDocument();      

            System.out.println(fileData);
            doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), fileData, null);

    }
    catch(Exception exep){exep.printStackTrace();}
```

Comment: it is an object you can pass it any where you like

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)

Comment: add a method to your Excelsheet which takes a value (it can be jTextpane or just a string ) then pass the value to ExcelSheet object with that method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Action`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) to encapsulate the code that updates the text pane in order to display a given file. You can invoke the action from a [`ListSelectionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/listselectionlistener.html) added to your `JList`. You can also use the action in a menu item or a toolbar button, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4039359/230513). [`ImageApp`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5129757/230513) is a related example.

For example,  each instance of your action will need the target text pane and file:

```
class FileAction extends AbstractAction {

    JTextPane target;
    File file;

    public FileAction(JTextPane target, File file) {
        this.target = target;
        this.file = file;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // render file in target
    }
}
```