# How to select an Item from a JList among other JLists in the same JPanel

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jlist

I'm working on a small File Management program in Eclipse(Version:Kepler). Also am new to Java Programming.

I designed a JPanel in a JFrame, where there are two JScrollPanes each containing a JList. The two JLists are programmed to show a list of files in two separate folders(i.e. JList1 shows list of files in Folder A and JList2 shows list of files in Folder B). Also there is a button for selection.

I need to program the button in such a way that only one Item is selected i.e. if I select an Item in JList1 then only that Item gets selected, not any Item in JList2 and vice-versa.

Its something to do with focus methods but I don't know how. I've searched the web, but search-results show item selection in one JList (not two JLists in the same panel).

Sample Codes would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

[`PanelBrowser`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15104660/230513) is an example that uses `ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION` to preclude multiple selection.

Addendum: *How do I determine that the currently selected Item is of JList1?*

You can use a `ListSelectionListener`, as shown in the [example cited](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15104660/230513) above and [*How to Write a List Selection Listener*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/listselectionlistener.html). Also consider [`Action`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html), shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16445050/230513).

[image]

Comment: BrowsePanel is a great program. But I didn't meant ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION. I mean am looking for a method related to focus(i.e. JList1 is currently focused if I select an Item of that list). How do I determine that the currently selected Item is of JList1 ?

Comment: I've elaborated above.