# Background color won't change in panel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, setbackground

The following code produces a window with buttons, but an error message pops up when I run i and actally press the button. According to the Spring tooltip:

```
Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method setBackground(Color) from the type JComponent
```

This program is literally entered from my Java textbook line for line, as far as I can tell. It's an older book, so there might be incompatibility, but it doesn't seem likely.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ButtonTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        final ButtonFrame frame = new ButtonFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.show();
}
}

class ButtonFrame extends JFrame
{
    public ButtonFrame()
    {
    setTitle("Button Test");
    setSize(Default_width, Default_height);

        //panel
        ButtonPanel panel = new ButtonPanel();
        Container contentPane=getContentPane();
        contentPane.add(panel);
    }

    public static final int Default_width = 300;
public static final int Default_height = 200;
}

class ButtonPanel extends JPanel
{
public ButtonPanel()
{
    JButton yellowButton = new JButton("Yellow");
    JButton blueButton = new JButton("Blue");
    JButton redButton = new JButton("Red");

    add(yellowButton);
    add(blueButton);
    add(redButton);

    ColorAction yellowAction= new ColorAction(Color.YELLOW);
    ColorAction redAction = new ColorAction(Color.RED);
    ColorAction blueAction = new ColorAction(Color.BLUE);

    yellowButton.addActionListener(yellowAction);
    blueButton.addActionListener(blueAction);
    redButton.addActionListener(redAction);
    }
}

    class ColorAction implements ActionListener
    {
        public ColorAction(Color c)
    {
        backgroundColor=c;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {
    ButtonPanel.setBackground(backgroundColor);
    }

        private Color backgroundColor;
}
```

Comment: `frame.show();`  Don't ignore deprecation warnings.

Comment: +1 for an [sscce](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach is to [*nest*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) `ColorAction` as an *inner class* in `ButtonPanel`, where it has implicit access to the enclosing panel.

Addendum: As noted in comments by @Andrew Thompson and @nachokk, the implicit accessibility can be made explicit by qualifying `this` using the enclosing class name. See [*JLS §15.8.4. Qualified* `this`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.4) for details. In this example, these two invocations are equivalent:

```
 setBackground(backgroundColor);
 ButtonPanel.this.setBackground(backgroundColor);
```

As an more general alternative, consider encapsulating the target panel and color in an `Action`, as outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16445050/230513).

[image]

```
class ButtonPanel extends JPanel {

    public ButtonPanel() {
        JButton yellowButton = new JButton("Yellow");
        JButton blueButton = new JButton("Blue");
        JButton redButton = new JButton("Red");

        add(yellowButton);
        add(blueButton);
        add(redButton);

        ColorAction yellowAction = new ColorAction(Color.YELLOW);
        ColorAction redAction = new ColorAction(Color.RED);
        ColorAction blueAction = new ColorAction(Color.BLUE);

        yellowButton.addActionListener(yellowAction);
        blueButton.addActionListener(blueAction);
        redButton.addActionListener(redAction);
    }

    private class ColorAction implements ActionListener {

        public ColorAction(Color c) {
            backgroundColor = c;
        }

         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            setBackground(backgroundColor);
        }
        private Color backgroundColor;
    }
}
```

Comment: See also [§15.8.4. Qualified this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.4). -- That was a comment posted on a (now deleted) answer that was the only part worth repeating.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: I defer to you, but I found your argument for clarity to be cogent, should you restore your answer.

Comment: The bulk of the answer was wrong for this question (given the code structure).  If I did resurrect any part of it, it would only be as a comment.

Comment: Also, @AndrewThompson Thank you for both your help, and for saying that your the "this.setbackground" fix was incorrect. I had tried this before and was worried that there was something wrong with my compiler that was causing it to fail.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. :)

Answer (score 2):

[ButtonPanel.setBackground()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html?is-external=true#setBackground%28java.awt.Color%29)
is not a static method so you can't call it as one. You need a concrete instance of ButtonPanel to set the background.

```
ButtonPanel bp = new ButtonPanel();
bp.setBackground(backgroundColor);
```

Answer (score 0):

Also change in look and feel can help:

```
//UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName());
```