# How to use jFileChooser's open button in java?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe, jfilechooser

Currently I am using Netbeans. I have added a **jFileChooser** in a **jFrame**. All is ok, but when I select a file and click on the Open button of the **jFileChooser** it happens nothings. I want to get the selected file's address path when the button is clicked. How can I write code for the button?

Comment: Show us the code to help you better?

Comment: here is the code.

`private void addfileActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        FileChooser fc = new FileChooser();
        fc.setVisible(true);
    }`
@Smit

Comment: Did you read the Swing tutorial on [How to Use File Choosers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html) for a working example?

Comment: Can you please edit your post, that would be helpful

Comment: @Tushar Please add those code to your question. Code as comment is unreadable. Moreover I never seen `addfileActionPerformed` method. Are you creating your own method? Give us the code where we can replicate the problem. We all can keep of guessing but that wont be fruitful. Also follow link given by @ camickr..

Comment: Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) if you continue to have problems.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this when the listener of the button is activated:

```
String filePath = myFileChooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
```

Of course, you may not want to store it in a String, but hey, just an example.

Answer (score 1):

Check the chooser's return value. If it's the `APPROVE_OPTION`, `getSelectedFile()` will return the selected `File`. This complete [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5129757/230513) follows [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html) almost verbatim in `ImageOpenAction`.

Comment: But i can't get the open button clicked. When I'm trying to add action performed for open button, the whole frame is selected.

Comment: @AvinashRaj: try the [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5129757/230513) and open a new question if you still have problems.

Answer (score 0):

If you added the `JFileChooser` control to your `JFrame`, you should not instantiate another `JFileChooser`. Just add two lines:

```
JFileChooser chooser = (JFileChooser) evt.getSource();
```

and the line that Asier Aranbarri gave in his answer and use your variable name (e.g. `chooser`) instead of `myFileChooser`.

By the way, if you want to know whether the Open or the Cancel button was pressed get the event command:

```
String command = evt.getCommand();
```

The string will either contain `"ApproveSelection"` (Open button) or `"CancelSelection"` (Close button).