# Keylistener on jpanel won't work

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, keylistener

I'm trying to add a keylistener to my JPanel but it won't work even after this:

```
put.setFocusable(true);
    put.requestFocusInWindow();
    KeyboardHandler keyhandler=new KeyboardHandler();
    put.addKeyListener(keyhandler);
}
private class KeyboardHandler implements KeyListener{
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    System.out.println("OVDE ZZZ");
    if(e.getKeyCode()==17) ctrl=true;
        if(e.getKeyCode()==90) z=true;
        if(ctrl && z){
            if (UndoBrojac==0) JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You can't undo that");
            else{
                UndoBrojac--;
                put.setUndo(UndoBrojac);
            }
        }

}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){
    if (e.getKeyCode()==17) ctrl = false;
    if (e.getKeyCode()==90) z = false;
}

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}
}
```

**I'm trying to add ctrl+z but it doesn't work.**

Comment: You should use `KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL` and `KeyEvent.VK_Z` to avoid magic constants.

Comment: thats not a problem now, it won't even get to keypressed

Comment: For Swing, typically use key bindings over the AWT based, lower level, `KeyListener`.  See [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for details on how to use them.

Comment: Why would it work ? It requires the component to have focus, and I guess in your terms the top-level container is getting the focus, so use KeyBinding as already suggested :-) This post regarding [Motion using Keyboard](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/motion-using-the-keyboard/), by @camickr will definitely interest you :-)

Comment: I found that focus must be done after being set to visible, so creating a new class now

Comment: what happened when you typed _swing keylistener not working_ into the search field in the upper trailing edge of this or any other page of the site?

Comment: A lot of stuff appeared, tried a lot of them. Didn't work

Comment: well, that's probably because you didn't follow the answers ;-) The one I choose as the duplicate (in voting to close) mentions both the focus issue and that you should _not_ use a keyListener - so why didn't you learn from that, update your approach accordingly and then come back?

Comment: See also [*Implementing Undo and Redo*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#undo).

Answer (score 2):

Several helpful comments suggest using [*Key Bindings*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html). As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5129757/230513), it is particularly easy to specify `KeyEvent.VK_Z` as an `ACCELERATOR_KEY` in the context of an [`Action`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html). If you are undoing changes to a text component, see [*How to Write an Undoable Edit Listener*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/undoableeditlistener.html); the [`TextComponentDemo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/index.html#TextComponentDemo) cited there illustrates a typical `UndoAction`.