# Creating a popup window on button click using JPanel from another JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jbutton, popupwindow

I am using netbeans to create a GUI for a tool I am working on. The tools contents are contained in a class that extends JPanel and has a button. When I click the button, I want a window to pop up which will have additional buttons and options, the contents of which are defined in another class that also extends JPanel.  How can I accomplish this?

Simplified code of main class. I removed all the code that is not important to this problem:

```
public class FirstPanel extends JPanel {

    private JButton myButton;

    public FirstPanel() {

        myButton = new JButton("Button");
        myButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

                // TO DO

            }
        });
    }
}
```

And then my second class would look similar, and be in charge of handling all of its buttons and such.  How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

See [*How to Use Menus: Bringing Up a Popup Menu*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html#popup) for the correct way to handle this in a cross-platform `MouseListener`. Even more simply, use `setComponentPopupMenu()`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5129757/230513). In either case, note the use of [`Action`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) to encapsulate the desired functionality.

Answer (score 0):

use something like

```
if (evt.getModifiers() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3_MASK){  
    popup.show(evt.getComponent(), evt.getX(), evt.getY());//show popup 
}
```

Comment: @user3280809: If you go this route, use [`isPopupTrigger()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html#popup) instead.