# Set Multiple Masks for KeyStroke

Tags: java, macos, swing, keyboard-shortcuts, keystroke

How would I go about making a keystone with multiple modifier masks? With the lack of explicitly specifying the command mask, Apple recommends this, for getting the mask:

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getMenuShortcutMask();
```

In an example:

```
KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_N, Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getMenuShortcutMask();
```

On OS X, This would allow me to use this accelerator: <kbd>Cmd+N</kbd>/ <kbd>⌘N</kbd>. It shows on the menu bar too:

[image: Menu Bar]

However, what if I need to combine modifier masks? Like so: <kbd>Cmd+Option+N</kbd>/<kbd>⌘⌥N</kbd>. I've tried this:

```
KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("command option n");
```

But it doesn't do it. `java.awt.Toolkit` doesn't seem to give me this option. So how can I add multiple masks to set as the accelerator?

Comment: I've not tried, but in theory, you should be able to bitwise or the modifiers `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getMenuShortcutMask() | KeyEvent.VK_ALT_DOWN_MASK` or some such

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The toolkit's `getMenuShortcutKeyMask()` returns `InputEvent.META_MASK` on Mac OS X. You can add `InputEvent.ALT_MASK` to that to get <kbd>⌥⌘N</kbd>.

```
private static final int MASK =
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getMenuShortcutKeyMask();
…
KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_N, MASK | InputEvent.ALT_MASK)
```

Starting with this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5129757/230513) produces the result pictured:

[image]

Comment: You are genius. You've solved my problems!!!! :D Just for anyone else who comes here, please don't substitute `KeyEvent` for `InputEvent`, you won't get the same result. :)